# hide boxes if div width gets smaller

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, width

I made an example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/0yn7sbbr/4/

I want the boxes to be hidden on resize starting from n to 0, till none remains, only the fixed box is left.

In the example, after n goes down and is hidden with overflow, i want that the remaining boxes to move to the right with no space in between.

Thank you in advances.

I don't know javascript/jquery.

Comment: You do know a bit of jQuery, you made a JSfiddle. I believe this can be achieved in pure CSS, no need for JS. If you want a perfect layout without gaps, have a look at the Flexbox property : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Kal-Ei, there was a mistake in the fiddle. I updated it and it is working now

Comment: This should be achievable using pure CSS. Look into Media Queries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mostly CSS solution  with jQuery**

Instead of using floats for `.box`, I would use inline blocks and use `text-align: right` to keep them flush right.

Note the extra space between the `.box` elements, but that can be easily fixed in the HTML code by remove and space characters in the mark-up.

This takes care of all but the last box.

To hide the last box, you need to use JavaScript/jQuery.

See fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/audetwebdesign/6o9rgmca/

Comment: Thank you Marc, i've put the code in a fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/haubfwdc/ . The last box still shows there. Your answer is the best so far.

Comment: Box 1 is the last one, in the end there can be only one. The fixed one... and Duncan MacLeod. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for all your time Marc! You're the best! I cant vote up your answer because i don't have 15 points reputation yet.

Comment: @Kal-El Please check updated fiddle, I have something that is pretty close to what you need, especially the jQuery component.

Comment: @Kal-El You can still accept the answer if it works for you.  Good luck and welcome to SO!

Comment: @Kal-El Accept the answer so that people know that the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can just check the width of `.wrapper` itself, no need to include `window` in there

```
if ($('.wrapper').width() < 52)
```

Second, include the `if` condition in the resize handler itself

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $('#widthSpan').html($('.wrapper').width());

   if ($('.wrapper').width() < 52) {
     $('div.wrapper').hide();
   }
});
```

See updated [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/0yn7sbbr/7/)

Comment: What is the difference in fiddle?

Comment: @Manoz, there was a mistake in the fiddle. I updated it and it is working now

Comment: Still the same. I think you didn't get the question. As OP wants no space between the divs. Re sizing has no issues.

Comment: Thank you Manoz, you are very observant, There is still a space between the boxes.

Comment: @Kal-El wait, so is the problem the space only?

Comment: Smaller bug in jQuery, you need "$('.wrapper').width() <= 52" otherwise the if clause is never satisfied.  The fixed element has a width of 52px, so the page width will never shrink to less than 52px, so you need to check for the equality.